# ggplot2: boxplot incorrectly calculated

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to create a boxplot of two variables and addtionally visualize the oberverations with points. While the latter worked out as I wantes, my boxplot is wrong. For example the mean for the first variables should be 6.2 and for the second 5.0 Does anyone have a solution who to fix it? Thank you a lot!

Here you can see my code and my data:

```
EB2 <- EB1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())  %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T))


EB2%>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point( aes(size = count, colour = value))+
  scale_colour_viridis_c(aesthetics = "colour")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
structure(list(bedeutung_vielfalt = c("9", "1", "7", "0", "5", 
"1", "1", "6", "8", "9", "2", "6", "10", "0", "6", "7", "2", 
"7", "8", "4", "6", "6", "2", "10", "7", "4", "0", "7", "0", 
"8", "8", "7", "3", "4", "0", "10", "6", "0", "9", "10", "10", 
"5", "3", "9", "7", "6", "8", "9", "8", "3", "10", "5", "8", 
"2", "7", "8", "9", "7", "7", "8", "3", "7", "0", "8", "8", "8", 
"6", "2", "7", "2", "4", "8", "9", "8", "7", "5", "7", "8", "7", 
"10", "10", "3", "2", "7", "9", "5", "10", "10", "7", "7", "5", 
"10", "2", "8", "7", "5", "0", "10", "8", "7", "0", "6", "5", 
"0", "0", "7", "9", "8", "8", "4", "2", "5", "9", "1", "8", "7", 
"10", "8", "8", "5", "7", "10", "8", "5", "0", "9", "5", "7", 
"5", "6", "0", "2", "3", "0", "3", "2", "10", "7", "4", "8", 
"5", "5", "7", "7", "2", "0", "2", "7", "2", "7", "7", "10", 
"10", "8", "7", "5", "9", "2", "9", "2", "3", "5", "7", "6", 
"10", "8", "9", "1", "5", "4", "7", "5", "10", "5", "8", "10", 
"7", "10", "8", "6", "8", "4", "8", "9", "10", "7", "0", "2", 
"8", "4", "8", "3", "10", "2", "7", "8", "7", "10", "7", "3", 
"0", "8", "5", "6", "5", "7", "7", "6", "6", "5", "6", "7", "7", 
"10", "5", "8", "8", "10", "2", "7", "3", "8", "8", "4", "6", 
"5", "4", "2", "2", "5", "7", "5", "7", "7", "7", "3", "6", "7", 
"6", "4", "10", "10", "8", "9", "4", "10", "2", "0", "0", "7", 
"0", "9", "7", "8", "6", "5", "5", "2", "8", "5", "8", "5", "5", 
"7", "10", "7", "8", "10", "8", "5", "2", "8", "8", "7", "5", 
"8", "3", "8", "6", "7", "7", "8", "9", "5", "8", "9", "6", "7", 
"5", "9", "8", "4", "10", "1", "4", "5", "10", "2", "3", "10", 
"7", "1", "4", "5", "10", "6", "10", "3", "7", "7", "7", "4", 
"3", "9", "8", "7", "5", "2", "7", "10", "8", "10", "5", "1", 
"6", "5", "9", "10", "10", "5", "8", "8", "10", "8", "8", "8", 
"8", "2", "10", "8", "10", "8", "7", "8", "9", "7", "4", "10", 
"2", "3", "7", "0", "5", "7", "8", "7", "10", "10", "10", "2", 
"8", "9", "6", "10", "5", "10", "0", "6", "10", "10", "9", "8", 
"7", "7", "8", "5", "8", "1", "5", "8", "8", "8", "9", "2", "7", 
"8", "5", "9", "8", "7", "9", "6", "10", "6", "7", "5", "8", 
"10", "10", "9", "8", "9", "7", "2", "4", "10", "4", "8", "7", 
"6", "4", "10", "4", "0", "7", "8", "7", "5", "8", "8", "6", 
"7", "4", "8", "10", "8", "6", "4", "9", "8", "10", "9", "10", 
"7", "10", "8", "5", "8", "10", "7", "8", "8", "6", "6", "5", 
"7", "1", "7", "7", "5", "3", "5", "10", "3", "8", "7", "5", 
"9", "6"), austausch_vielfalt = c("4", "0", "4", "5", "7", "1", 
"1", "6", "7", "8", "2", "5", "0", "0", "4", "5", "0", "6", "5", 
"4", "2", "4", "0", "7", "7", "4", "0", "5", "0", "0", "8", "9", 
"3", "6", "0", "8", "9", "0", "9", "8", "10", "1", "1", "7", 
"4", "6", "8", "5", "7", "8", "7", "5", "2", "2", "7", "5", "5", 
"6", "6", "6", "2", "5", "3", "8", "5", "4", "5", "7", "4", "2", 
"5", "8", "5", "8", "10", "5", "3", "4", "5", "9", "9", "2", 
"2", "5", "6", "7", "9", "5", "6", "4", "2", "10", "2", "8", 
"6", "5", "0", "10", "3", "5", "0", "5", "5", "1", "0", "6", 
"9", "4", "5", "3", "0", "5", "7", "0", "5", "2", "8", "3", "4", 
"5", "5", "10", "3", "2", "0", "4", "4", "3", "4", "2", "0", 
"0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "10", "6", "1", "8", "9", "4", "5", 
"7", "2", "0", "5", "5", "1", "7", "6", "9", "5", "8", "6", "2", 
"9", "0", "7", "2", "0", "3", "3", "3", "10", "6", "7", "0", 
"1", "2", "3", "3", "10", "0", "7", "10", "4", "5", "7", "4", 
"8", "2", "7", "8", "8", "5", "0", "3", "8", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "7", "8", "5", "6", "3", "0", "5", "5", "5", "4", "5", "5", 
"5", "2", "5", "5", "3", "7", "7", "7", "3", "6", "10", "4", 
"1", "5", "3", "6", "7", "3", "3", "0", "1", "5", "2", "7", "4", 
"1", "3", "3", "7", "3", "6", "5", "3", "6", "5", "5", "5", "8", 
"2", "9", "2", "5", "0", "4", "0", "9", "4", "6", "6", "7", "2", 
"2", "8", "1", "6", "3", "2", "8", "8", "9", "9", "8", "5", "5", 
"1", "7", "6", "4", "3", "3", "7", "7", "2", "9", "3", "5", "10", 
"1", "0", "6", "6", "3", "5", "7", "7", "6", "10", "1", "3", 
"4", "10", "5", "0", "10", "6", "3", "7", "5", "6", "6", "10", 
"2", "6", "7", "7", "4", "5", "8", "5", "7", "4", "1", "5", "4", 
"6", "5", "5", "2", "4", "4", "9", "7", "7", "2", "6", "5", "3", 
"5", "5", "8", "7", "1", "8", "8", "9", "8", "6", "8", "9", "5", 
"0", "8", "4", "1", "0", "0", "5", "6", "7", "7", "10", "10", 
"10", "1", "5", "8", "4", "9", "5", "10", "0", "4", "8", "10", 
"6", "5", "8", "2", "8", "3", "5", "3", "5", "9", "7", "7", "8", 
"2", "8", "8", "5", "7", "5", "5", "10", "4", "9", "5", "5", 
"5", "3", "8", "10", "8", "4", "7", "7", "5", "2", "10", "4", 
"6", "3", "4", "3", "6", "1", "10", "6", "8", "8", "5", "7", 
"8", "8", "6", "2", "8", "7", "7", "6", "6", "6", "5", "6", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "8", "7", "7", "9", "10", "4", "5", "3", "3", 
"3", "7", "7", "5", "5", "8", "7", "10", "8", "3", "5", "6", 
"7", "6", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -459L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, 
`3` = 3L, `4` = 4L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, 
`14` = 14L, `17` = 17L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, 
`25` = 25L, `26` = 26L, `27` = 27L, `28` = 28L, `29` = 29L, `30` = 30L, 
`33` = 33L, `34` = 34L, `36` = 36L, `37` = 37L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, 
`41` = 41L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, `46` = 46L, `48` = 48L, 
`55` = 55L, `56` = 56L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `61` = 61L, 
`62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `67` = 67L, 
`70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `74` = 74L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, 
`78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, `80` = 80L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, 
`85` = 85L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `91` = 91L, `92` = 92L, `94` = 94L, 
`95` = 95L, `97` = 97L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L, 
`102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L, 
`107` = 107L, `111` = 111L, `112` = 112L, `114` = 114L, `115` = 115L, 
`116` = 116L, `118` = 118L, `119` = 119L, `121` = 121L, `122` = 122L, 
`123` = 123L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, 
`129` = 129L, `131` = 131L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, `134` = 134L, 
`135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, `137` = 137L, `142` = 142L, `147` = 147L, 
`149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, `152` = 152L, `154` = 154L, 
`155` = 155L, `159` = 159L, `162` = 162L, `164` = 164L, `166` = 166L, 
`177` = 177L, `178` = 178L, `182` = 182L, `184` = 184L, `186` = 186L, 
`188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `191` = 191L, `192` = 192L, `194` = 194L, 
`195` = 195L, `196` = 196L, `198` = 198L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L, 
`203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `208` = 208L, `213` = 213L, `216` = 216L, 
`220` = 220L, `226` = 226L, `232` = 232L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L, 
`237` = 237L, `239` = 239L, `240` = 240L, `243` = 243L, `244` = 244L, 
`247` = 247L, `248` = 248L, `257` = 257L, `262` = 262L, `264` = 264L, 
`267` = 267L, `268` = 268L, `269` = 269L, `271` = 271L, `276` = 276L, 
`278` = 278L, `281` = 281L, `293` = 293L, `294` = 294L, `296` = 296L, 
`297` = 297L, `300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `304` = 304L, `313` = 313L, 
`320` = 320L, `322` = 322L, `326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, 
`331` = 331L, `332` = 332L, `333` = 333L, `336` = 336L, `346` = 346L, 
`349` = 349L, `352` = 352L, `355` = 355L, `363` = 363L, `366` = 366L, 
`371` = 371L, `375` = 375L, `382` = 382L, `403` = 403L, `404` = 404L, 
`410` = 410L, `411` = 411L, `413` = 413L, `417` = 417L, `419` = 419L, 
`421` = 421L, `422` = 422L, `424` = 424L, `426` = 426L, `427` = 427L, 
`428` = 428L, `431` = 431L, `432` = 432L, `438` = 438L, `440` = 440L, 
`442` = 442L, `444` = 444L, `447` = 447L, `448` = 448L, `449` = 449L, 
`450` = 450L, `452` = 452L, `453` = 453L, `454` = 454L, `455` = 455L, 
`472` = 472L, `473` = 473L, `479` = 479L, `481` = 481L, `491` = 491L, 
`493` = 493L, `496` = 496L, `499` = 499L, `509` = 509L, `512` = 512L, 
`514` = 514L, `518` = 518L, `542` = 542L, `570` = 570L, `571` = 571L, 
`588` = 588L, `589` = 589L, `597` = 597L, `599` = 599L, `600` = 600L, 
`603` = 603L, `604` = 604L, `619` = 619L, `621` = 621L, `622` = 622L, 
`623` = 623L, `625` = 625L, `632` = 632L, `633` = 633L, `640` = 640L, 
`643` = 643L, `650` = 650L, `651` = 651L, `652` = 652L, `653` = 653L, 
`654` = 654L, `656` = 656L, `658` = 658L, `660` = 660L, `662` = 662L, 
`663` = 663L, `666` = 666L, `667` = 667L, `668` = 668L, `669` = 669L, 
`670` = 670L, `679` = 679L, `681` = 681L, `682` = 682L, `687` = 687L, 
`690` = 690L, `691` = 691L, `694` = 694L, `697` = 697L, `699` = 699L, 
`702` = 702L, `703` = 703L, `704` = 704L, `715` = 715L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Your values are `1:10` in both cases. The box plots are therefore correct (two uniform distributions of 10 values). But you probably want to show box plots of the *original* (= non-summarised) data.

Comment: Exactly! thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Right, so do that.

Comment: I dont know how, thats why I am asking

Comment: Boxplots don't show mean values

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? The boxplot shows the median, so I've summarised into a separate dataframe and added the mean as a label using only the summarised data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

EB1 <- structure(list(bedeutung_vielfalt = c("9", "1", "7", "0", "5", 
                                      "1", "1", "6", "8", "9", "2", "6", "10", "0", "6", "7", "2", 
                                      "7", "8", "4", "6", "6", "2", "10", "7", "4", "0", "7", "0", 
                                      "8", "8", "7", "3", "4", "0", "10", "6", "0", "9", "10", "10", 
                                      "5", "3", "9", "7", "6", "8", "9", "8", "3", "10", "5", "8", 
                                      "2", "7", "8", "9", "7", "7", "8", "3", "7", "0", "8", "8", "8", 
                                      "6", "2", "7", "2", "4", "8", "9", "8", "7", "5", "7", "8", "7", 
                                      "10", "10", "3", "2", "7", "9", "5", "10", "10", "7", "7", "5", 
                                      "10", "2", "8", "7", "5", "0", "10", "8", "7", "0", "6", "5", 
                                      "0", "0", "7", "9", "8", "8", "4", "2", "5", "9", "1", "8", "7", 
                                      "10", "8", "8", "5", "7", "10", "8", "5", "0", "9", "5", "7", 
                                      "5", "6", "0", "2", "3", "0", "3", "2", "10", "7", "4", "8", 
                                      "5", "5", "7", "7", "2", "0", "2", "7", "2", "7", "7", "10", 
                                      "10", "8", "7", "5", "9", "2", "9", "2", "3", "5", "7", "6", 
                                      "10", "8", "9", "1", "5", "4", "7", "5", "10", "5", "8", "10", 
                                      "7", "10", "8", "6", "8", "4", "8", "9", "10", "7", "0", "2", 
                                      "8", "4", "8", "3", "10", "2", "7", "8", "7", "10", "7", "3", 
                                      "0", "8", "5", "6", "5", "7", "7", "6", "6", "5", "6", "7", "7", 
                                      "10", "5", "8", "8", "10", "2", "7", "3", "8", "8", "4", "6", 
                                      "5", "4", "2", "2", "5", "7", "5", "7", "7", "7", "3", "6", "7", 
                                      "6", "4", "10", "10", "8", "9", "4", "10", "2", "0", "0", "7", 
                                      "0", "9", "7", "8", "6", "5", "5", "2", "8", "5", "8", "5", "5", 
                                      "7", "10", "7", "8", "10", "8", "5", "2", "8", "8", "7", "5", 
                                      "8", "3", "8", "6", "7", "7", "8", "9", "5", "8", "9", "6", "7", 
                                      "5", "9", "8", "4", "10", "1", "4", "5", "10", "2", "3", "10", 
                                      "7", "1", "4", "5", "10", "6", "10", "3", "7", "7", "7", "4", 
                                      "3", "9", "8", "7", "5", "2", "7", "10", "8", "10", "5", "1", 
                                      "6", "5", "9", "10", "10", "5", "8", "8", "10", "8", "8", "8", 
                                      "8", "2", "10", "8", "10", "8", "7", "8", "9", "7", "4", "10", 
                                      "2", "3", "7", "0", "5", "7", "8", "7", "10", "10", "10", "2", 
                                      "8", "9", "6", "10", "5", "10", "0", "6", "10", "10", "9", "8", 
                                      "7", "7", "8", "5", "8", "1", "5", "8", "8", "8", "9", "2", "7", 
                                      "8", "5", "9", "8", "7", "9", "6", "10", "6", "7", "5", "8", 
                                      "10", "10", "9", "8", "9", "7", "2", "4", "10", "4", "8", "7", 
                                      "6", "4", "10", "4", "0", "7", "8", "7", "5", "8", "8", "6", 
                                      "7", "4", "8", "10", "8", "6", "4", "9", "8", "10", "9", "10", 
                                      "7", "10", "8", "5", "8", "10", "7", "8", "8", "6", "6", "5", 
                                      "7", "1", "7", "7", "5", "3", "5", "10", "3", "8", "7", "5", 
                                      "9", "6"), austausch_vielfalt = c("4", "0", "4", "5", "7", "1", 
                                                                        "1", "6", "7", "8", "2", "5", "0", "0", "4", "5", "0", "6", "5", 
                                                                        "4", "2", "4", "0", "7", "7", "4", "0", "5", "0", "0", "8", "9", 
                                                                        "3", "6", "0", "8", "9", "0", "9", "8", "10", "1", "1", "7", 
                                                                        "4", "6", "8", "5", "7", "8", "7", "5", "2", "2", "7", "5", "5", 
                                                                        "6", "6", "6", "2", "5", "3", "8", "5", "4", "5", "7", "4", "2", 
                                                                        "5", "8", "5", "8", "10", "5", "3", "4", "5", "9", "9", "2", 
                                                                        "2", "5", "6", "7", "9", "5", "6", "4", "2", "10", "2", "8", 
                                                                        "6", "5", "0", "10", "3", "5", "0", "5", "5", "1", "0", "6", 
                                                                        "9", "4", "5", "3", "0", "5", "7", "0", "5", "2", "8", "3", "4", 
                                                                        "5", "5", "10", "3", "2", "0", "4", "4", "3", "4", "2", "0", 
                                                                        "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "10", "6", "1", "8", "9", "4", "5", 
                                                                        "7", "2", "0", "5", "5", "1", "7", "6", "9", "5", "8", "6", "2", 
                                                                        "9", "0", "7", "2", "0", "3", "3", "3", "10", "6", "7", "0", 
                                                                        "1", "2", "3", "3", "10", "0", "7", "10", "4", "5", "7", "4", 
                                                                        "8", "2", "7", "8", "8", "5", "0", "3", "8", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
                                                                        "2", "7", "8", "5", "6", "3", "0", "5", "5", "5", "4", "5", "5", 
                                                                        "5", "2", "5", "5", "3", "7", "7", "7", "3", "6", "10", "4", 
                                                                        "1", "5", "3", "6", "7", "3", "3", "0", "1", "5", "2", "7", "4", 
                                                                        "1", "3", "3", "7", "3", "6", "5", "3", "6", "5", "5", "5", "8", 
                                                                        "2", "9", "2", "5", "0", "4", "0", "9", "4", "6", "6", "7", "2", 
                                                                        "2", "8", "1", "6", "3", "2", "8", "8", "9", "9", "8", "5", "5", 
                                                                        "1", "7", "6", "4", "3", "3", "7", "7", "2", "9", "3", "5", "10", 
                                                                        "1", "0", "6", "6", "3", "5", "7", "7", "6", "10", "1", "3", 
                                                                        "4", "10", "5", "0", "10", "6", "3", "7", "5", "6", "6", "10", 
                                                                        "2", "6", "7", "7", "4", "5", "8", "5", "7", "4", "1", "5", "4", 
                                                                        "6", "5", "5", "2", "4", "4", "9", "7", "7", "2", "6", "5", "3", 
                                                                        "5", "5", "8", "7", "1", "8", "8", "9", "8", "6", "8", "9", "5", 
                                                                        "0", "8", "4", "1", "0", "0", "5", "6", "7", "7", "10", "10", 
                                                                        "10", "1", "5", "8", "4", "9", "5", "10", "0", "4", "8", "10", 
                                                                        "6", "5", "8", "2", "8", "3", "5", "3", "5", "9", "7", "7", "8", 
                                                                        "2", "8", "8", "5", "7", "5", "5", "10", "4", "9", "5", "5", 
                                                                        "5", "3", "8", "10", "8", "4", "7", "7", "5", "2", "10", "4", 
                                                                        "6", "3", "4", "3", "6", "1", "10", "6", "8", "8", "5", "7", 
                                                                        "8", "8", "6", "2", "8", "7", "7", "6", "6", "6", "5", "6", "7", 
                                                                        "7", "7", "7", "8", "7", "7", "9", "10", "4", "5", "3", "3", 
                                                                        "3", "7", "7", "5", "5", "8", "7", "10", "8", "3", "5", "6", 
                                                                        "7", "6", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -459L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `3` = 3L, `4` = 4L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `14` = 14L, `17` = 17L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `25` = 25L, `26` = 26L, `27` = 27L, `28` = 28L, `29` = 29L, `30` = 30L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `33` = 33L, `34` = 34L, `36` = 36L, `37` = 37L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `41` = 41L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, `46` = 46L, `48` = 48L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `55` = 55L, `56` = 56L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `61` = 61L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `67` = 67L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `74` = 74L, `76` = 76L, `77` = 77L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, `80` = 80L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `85` = 85L, `87` = 87L, `88` = 88L, `91` = 91L, `92` = 92L, `94` = 94L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `95` = 95L, `97` = 97L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `107` = 107L, `111` = 111L, `112` = 112L, `114` = 114L, `115` = 115L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `116` = 116L, `118` = 118L, `119` = 119L, `121` = 121L, `122` = 122L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `123` = 123L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `129` = 129L, `131` = 131L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, `134` = 134L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, `137` = 137L, `142` = 142L, `147` = 147L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, `152` = 152L, `154` = 154L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `155` = 155L, `159` = 159L, `162` = 162L, `164` = 164L, `166` = 166L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `177` = 177L, `178` = 178L, `182` = 182L, `184` = 184L, `186` = 186L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `191` = 191L, `192` = 192L, `194` = 194L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `195` = 195L, `196` = 196L, `198` = 198L, `201` = 201L, `202` = 202L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `208` = 208L, `213` = 213L, `216` = 216L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `220` = 220L, `226` = 226L, `232` = 232L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `237` = 237L, `239` = 239L, `240` = 240L, `243` = 243L, `244` = 244L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `247` = 247L, `248` = 248L, `257` = 257L, `262` = 262L, `264` = 264L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `267` = 267L, `268` = 268L, `269` = 269L, `271` = 271L, `276` = 276L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `278` = 278L, `281` = 281L, `293` = 293L, `294` = 294L, `296` = 296L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `297` = 297L, `300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `304` = 304L, `313` = 313L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `320` = 320L, `322` = 322L, `326` = 326L, `327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `331` = 331L, `332` = 332L, `333` = 333L, `336` = 336L, `346` = 346L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `349` = 349L, `352` = 352L, `355` = 355L, `363` = 363L, `366` = 366L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `371` = 371L, `375` = 375L, `382` = 382L, `403` = 403L, `404` = 404L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `410` = 410L, `411` = 411L, `413` = 413L, `417` = 417L, `419` = 419L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `421` = 421L, `422` = 422L, `424` = 424L, `426` = 426L, `427` = 427L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `428` = 428L, `431` = 431L, `432` = 432L, `438` = 438L, `440` = 440L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `442` = 442L, `444` = 444L, `447` = 447L, `448` = 448L, `449` = 449L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `450` = 450L, `452` = 452L, `453` = 453L, `454` = 454L, `455` = 455L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `472` = 472L, `473` = 473L, `479` = 479L, `481` = 481L, `491` = 491L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `493` = 493L, `496` = 496L, `499` = 499L, `509` = 509L, `512` = 512L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `514` = 514L, `518` = 518L, `542` = 542L, `570` = 570L, `571` = 571L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `588` = 588L, `589` = 589L, `597` = 597L, `599` = 599L, `600` = 600L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `603` = 603L, `604` = 604L, `619` = 619L, `621` = 621L, `622` = 622L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `623` = 623L, `625` = 625L, `632` = 632L, `633` = 633L, `640` = 640L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `643` = 643L, `650` = 650L, `651` = 651L, `652` = 652L, `653` = 653L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `654` = 654L, `656` = 656L, `658` = 658L, `660` = 660L, `662` = 662L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `663` = 663L, `666` = 666L, `667` = 667L, `668` = 668L, `669` = 669L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `670` = 670L, `679` = 679L, `681` = 681L, `682` = 682L, `687` = 687L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `690` = 690L, `691` = 691L, `694` = 694L, `697` = 697L, `699` = 699L, 
                                                                                                                                                                           `702` = 702L, `703` = 703L, `704` = 704L, `715` = 715L), class = "omit"))

EB2 <- EB1 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())  %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value))

EB3 <- EB2 |> group_by(name) |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T),
            median = median(value, na.rm = T))

EB2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_label(aes(y = 1, label = mean), data = EB3) +
  scale_colour_viridis_c(aesthetics = "colour")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>